# What is the correct general form of Hamilton's equation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, time-evolution, poisson-brackets

Usually, Hamilton's equations of motion are given by:
$$ (1)\;\; \frac{dp}{dt} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} \;\;\; \text{   and 
  } \;\;\;(2)\;\; \frac{dq}{dt} =\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}.$$
Using Poisson's bracket one can generalize Hamilton's equation i.e. the time derivative of anything is given by the Poisson bracket of that thing with the Hamiltonian:
$$\frac{dF}{dt} = \{F,H\} $$
where $F$ is a function of $p$ and $q$, $H$ is the Hamiltonian, and Poisson bracket is defined as $$ \{A,B\} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial q}\frac{\partial B}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial A}{\partial p}\frac{\partial B}{\partial q}. $$ See page 108 of 'No-nonsense Classical Mechanics' by Jakob Schwichtenberg and page 172 of 'The Theoretical Minimum' by Susskind & Hrabovsky for details. However, in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Generalization_to_quantum_mechanics_through_Poisson_bracket), they are saying that the most general form of the Hamilton's equation of motion is $$\frac{dF}{dt} = \{F,H\} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}.$$
From where is the extra $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ coming from? Which one is correct?

Comment: In general $F=F(q,p,t)$. Then you can define a function $\mathcal F(t) := F(q(t),p(t),t)$. Calculating its derivative (and employing the equations of motion) yields your last equation. Long story short: Observables can, in principle, depend on time *explicitly* and not only through $q$ and $p$.

Comment: Okay. Just for clarification, does that mean in Susskind/Jakob's text, they assumed that F doesn't depend explicitly on time, right?

Comment: I don't know the context (i.e. I haven't read the specific parts of the books), but it seems very likely to me.

Answer (score 4):

Most generally the observable $F$ depends not only on $q(t)$ and $p(t)$,
but also depends on $t$ explicitly, i.e.
$$F=F(q,p,t)$$
Differentiating this with respect to time $t$ you get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dF}{dt}
&=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\frac{dq}{dt}
 +\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}\frac{dp}{dt}
 +\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \\
&=\frac{\partial F}{\partial q}\frac{\partial H}{dp}
 -\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}\frac{\partial H}{dq}
 +\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \\
&=\{F,H\}
 +\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} 
\end{align}$$